# Display shapefile map on web browser using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, zip, shapefile

I want to display shapefile map on the web browser using my angular2 application. Following is my code snippet and I use leaflet javascript library. But it fails in loading 'Geology.zip' file. Is there any specific way of loading zip files in angular applications? or any possible way of doing this?

```
var shpfile = new L.Shapefile('Geology.zip', {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties) {
            layer.bindPopup(Object.keys(feature.properties).map(function(k) {
                return k + ": " + feature.properties[k];
            }).join("<br />"), {
                maxHeight: 200
            });
        }
    }
});
shpfile.addTo(m);
shpfile.once("data:loaded", function() {
    console.log("finished loaded shapefile");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile/issues/53) this [library](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile),that you are tryingto use, is deprecated and from what I have tried it is not possible to install it using npm.

Therefore you can use f.i this [library](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js) to display a Shapefile using Leaflet after converting it to GeoJSON.

```
import 'leaflet';
import * as shp from 'shpjs';
declare let L;

ngOnInit() {
    const m = L.map('map').setView([34.74161249883172, 18.6328125], 2);
    const geo = L.geoJson({features: []}, { onEachFeature: function popUp(f, l) {
        const out = [];
        if (f.properties) {
            for (const key of Object.keys(f.properties)) {
                out.push(key + ' : ' + f.properties[key]);
            }
            l.bindPopup(out.join('<br />'));
        }
    }}).addTo(m);
    const base = 'your-shapefile.zip';
        shp(base).then(function(data) {
            geo.addData(data);
    });
}
```

However several errors arise and you can overcome them if you check this [demo](https://github.com/kboul/angular-leaflet-shapefile)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I managed to do it as in this git repo https://github.com/isharawijesinghe/Shapfile_Angular and it works fine. I feel it is better to have a look at your method too since the library I'm using is deprecated

Comment: No problem. For sure you should use up-to-date libraries instead of deprecated ones. But, anyways, it is your choice in the end!